# Ms SQL OBDC Driver can't connect to MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssl, linked-server

I set an OBDC Connector on my Microsoft SQL server to set up a linked server to a MySQL database. The driver worked fine, and has always worked, but just recently we upgraded the web server to an SSL connection and everything goes through HTTPS. Since then the OBDC driver has been unable to connect at all. Any help or advice on how to deal with this would be great, thank you.

Comment: A linked server connection over ODBC would not be using http or https, Which database was hosted on the web server? Perhaps some of the necessary ports were closed

Comment: Have you tried [updating the driver as well](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36434)? Maybe that will help.

Comment: Check the answer, turned just using the IP instead of the domain name worked, weird how it worked before without a problem, but now it works just how it used to, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the solution was using an IP address to connect to the server instead of the domain name. I was using `sql.example.com` to connect to the server, but when I changed it to the actual ip ex: `192.168.1.254` it then started working oddly